# What is the point of using max function for two lists?

Tags: python, list

I am reading a code about  kangaroo race;
It gets an input of x1 v1 and x2 v2. Like shown bleow.
I want to figure out what is the difference of using max(X,Y) and min(X,Y);
 where we could make max(x1,x2) and min(x1, x2); 
Please help me to understand it.

```
x1, v1, x2, v2 = map(int, raw_input().split())
X = [x1, v1]
Y = [x2, v2]
back = min(X, Y)
fwd = max(X, Y)
dist = fwd[0] - back[0]
while back[0] < fwd[0]:
    back[0] += back[1]
    fwd[0] += fwd[1]
    if fwd[0] - back[0] >= dist:
        break

print ["NO", "YES"][back[0] == fwd[0]]
```

Comment: Out of curiosity - where are you getting this code from? I'm just a bit worried that if you're starting off with Python and trying to learn - it's going to send you down the wrong path - it's really not great code :)

Comment: This appears to be a solution to the Week of Code 21 first question. It's not really a very good solution at all. You should consider co-ordinate geometry for that particular question, in fact.

Comment: @JonClements I got it from a contest of  [hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/w21/challenges/kangaroo/editorial)

Answer (score 2):

By default (without the optional `key` argument), passing lists into [`min`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min)/[`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) returns the list that has the largest first item (i.e. it compares the items at index `0`).<sup>1</sup> Just passing in `int`s would only return the greater integer. For this particular application, it makes sense to pass the lists, as the point with the larger x-value is needed for future calculations (rather than just the larger x-value itself).

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Actually, it is slightly more complicated than this. What it really does is: check the items at index 0 of both lists; if one is greater/less than the other return the list that has the larger/smaller value, otherwise if they are equal, it moves on to index 1; if they too are equal it moves on to index 2 and so on until it finds an index where the values are unequal.</sub>

**EDIT**

I was debating whether or not to include this in my answer, as I thought it might make the code even more confusing, but being that @Jon Clements has just added it as a comment I'll include it here.

Instead of doing:

```
X = [x1, v1]
Y = [x2, v2]
back = min(X, Y)
fwd = max(X, Y)
```

You could do just:

```
back, fwd = sorted(([x1, v1], [x2, v2]))
```

In theory, this method is faster as it only requires one comparison of the lists, but in my (limited) testing it was only marginally so. (Either way, it is probably a premature optimization.) I'll leave you to figure out how it works ;).

Comment: Or even just `back, fwd = (X, Y) if X < Y else (Y, X)` - that should pretty much trump everything else

Comment: Or if you like how the author of the OP's code writes his ternary operators: `back, fwd = ((Y, X), (X, Y))[X < Y]` xD.

Comment: Hahaha... unless you're stuck using 2.4 - that just makes me want to cry :)